# How to access the event log by knowing the contract address (golang)?

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, events, logs, golang

At the moment I develope dapps that use smart contract as storage for specific data. I use abigen to generate specific go binding to my contract. If someone try change state of the contract I use event for logging this action. But I am stuck, because I do not realy understand how can I view log history of specific event using go ethereum.

How can I use json rpc call of `eth_getlogs` method  and get all the logs that are stored in this contract address with  go ?

I will be appreciated for a snippet of code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you would first create a new filter (`eth_newFilter` + `eth_getFilterLogs`) and reuse that filter to perform the same query many times as well as listen for changes. However, you can also install an ad-hoc filter with `eth_getLogs`, referencing the topics you wish to search over.

A topic is a piece of data you are searching. For example, if you have the following event:

```
Transfer(address to, address from)
```

The following filter would search for all logs going to `0xb3904758c0d3bfc25746c47caa45b01da8930e19`:

```
[0x000000000000000000000000b3904758c0d3bfc25746c47caa45b01da8930e19, null]
```

This filter would search for all logs coming from `0xb3904758c0d3bfc25746c47caa45b01da8930e19`:

```
[null, 0x000000000000000000000000b3904758c0d3bfc25746c47caa45b01da8930e19]
```

And this filter would search for all logs going to `0xb3904758c0d3bfc25746c47caa45b01da8930e19` from `0x8cc19c7b50857abbfbeeed31c302319a075d4a9b`:

```
[0x000000000000000000000000b3904758c0d3bfc25746c47caa45b01da8930e19, 0x0000000000000000000000008cc19c7b50857abbfbeeed31c302319a075d4a9b
```

A full golang wrapper for RPC requests would look something like this:

```
// This needs to be instantiated
type EthereumClient struct {
  URL string
}

// Basic RPC repsonse format
type JSONRPCRequest struct {
  JSONRPC string        `json:"jsonrpc"`
  Method  string        `json:"method"`
  ID      int64         `json:"id"`
  Params  []interface{} `json:"params"`
}

// Base struct
type ResponseBase struct {
  JSONRPC string `json:"jsonrpc"`
  ID      int64  `json:"id"`
}

// Response struct based on below RPC methods
type Response struct {
  ResponseBase
  Result string `json:"result"`
}

// ToJSON marshals a JSONRPCRequest into JSON
func (req *JSONRPCRequest) ToJSON() ([]byte, error) {
  s, err := json.Marshal(req)
  if err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return s, nil
}

// Get logs given an array of topics
func (client *EthereumClient) Eth_getLogs(topics string[]) (string, error) {
  reqBody := JSONRPCRequest{
    JSONRPC: "2.0",
    ID:      1,
    Method:  "eth_sendRawTransaction",
    Params:  []interface{}{topics},
  }
  res, err := client.issueRequest(&reqBody)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }

  var clientResp Response
  err = json.Unmarshal(res, &clientResp)
  if err != nil {
    return "", err
  }
  return clientResp.Result, nil
}
```

The `EthereumClient` can be instantiated in a different package by something like this:

```
// Global client connection
var client = EthereumClient{}

// provider = e.g. 'localhost:8545'
func ConnectToRPC(provider string) {
  client = EthereumClient{provider}
}
```

This `client` can now be used to start a new filter and get the logs from that filter.

I don't have a specific example for this use case, but please see [this](https://github.com/GridPlus/client/blob/master/src/rpc/eth.go) for some examples of making RPC requests in Go.

Answer (score 0):

You can add contract address as a parameter to eth_getLogs call:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getLogs","params":[{"address":["YOUR_CONTRACT_ADDRESS"]}],"id":74}'
```

If you are interested in constantly polling for events update, you may first create a filter with [eth_newFilter](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_newfilter) and then ask for updates with [eth_getFilterChanges](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getfilterchanges).